# Passing an unitialized value into a function in C

Tags: c

I am a rather newbie C-programmer and I just learnt today that passing an uninitialized variable into another function in C-programming is considered a bad practice.

Here's an example of the mistake program I first made (bad practice if I understood correctly):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

float askDecimal(int loop, float sum, float decimal) {
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        printf("Please give a decimal number: ");
        scanf("%f", &decimal);
        getchar();
        sum = sum + decimal;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int loop;
    float sum = 0;
    float decimal;
    printf("How many times do you want to ask for a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &loop);
    getchar();
    sum = askDecimal(loop, sum, decimal); // here I am passing uninitialized decimal to a function.
    printf("The sum is: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

As I did some learning on the Internet, I concluded that good practice would actually to declare the `float decimal;` inside the `askDecimal` function.

Like this:

```
float askDecimal(int loop, float sum) {
    float decimal;
    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
        printf("Please give a decimal number: ");
        scanf("%f", &decimal);
        getchar();
        sum = sum + decimal;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And the `main` function like this:

```
int main(void) {
    int loop;
    float sum = 0;
    printf("How many times do you want to ask for a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &loop);
    getchar();
    sum = askDecimal(loop, sum); // passing uninitialized decimal to a function.
    printf("The sum is: %f", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**If** I understood correctly, it is considered as bad practice to pass `uninitialized` variable into another function because you can easily by mistake use the uninitialized variable inside the function without first initializing it and thus causing undefined behaviour?

But, could a C programmer still pass the uninitialized variables into functions, if the programmer just is 100 % certain to assign a value to it inside the function first before using it inside the function?

Comment: `decimal` appears rather useless in all cases here ..

Comment: Since you don't use the value of `decimal` that's passed in, why are you passing it at all? It should just be a local variable in the function.

Comment: This isn't really about the uninitialized variable IMHO. Why do you even want to pass `decimal` into the function? It is *good practice*, to create your variables as locally as possible. Your first `askDecimal` function would confuse me a lot if I encountered it in the wild.
Concerning uninitialized variables (and giving a kind-of NULL answer): if it does not matter, you don't have to initialize them (like in your case, where you never read its value). If it does matter, then you should initialize your variables.

Comment: Why is `askDecimal()` returning `sum`, which is just the variable that was pass into it? It seems like it should return `decimal`.

Comment: what is the point of the loop in askDecimal?

Comment: And what's the reason for the loop? It just asks for that many decimal numbers, but doesn't do anything with them.

Comment: _" I just learnt today that passing an uninitialized variable into another function is bad practice":_ where did you learn this? Actually it not bad practice, it's utterly pointless.

Comment: I just made a few changes to the program. My purpose is to sum all the decimal numbers inside the function and return the sum.

Comment: There are a number of issues here. First, no sum is accumulated in askDecimal(); the value passed in (initialized to 0) will be returned. Second, if askDecimal() did accumulate sum, the value is lost upon return since it’s called with a local variable in main. A *copy* of sum is passed; if you want askDecimal() to change its value you have to pass its address. Better to not use it as an argument; instead, define (and initialize) it in askDecimal() and save askDecimal()’s return in the main().

Comment: Re: your original question, it’s pretty weird practice to define a variable and use it only in the called function, initialized or not.

Answer (score 6):

> But, could a C programmer still pass the uninitialized variables into functions, if the programmer just is 100 % certain to assign a value to it inside the function first before using it inside the function?

If the function is guaranteed to overwrite the variable before using it, it shouldn't be a parameter in the first place. It should be a local variable in the function.

If it's intended as an *output* parameter, you would pass a pointer to the variable, not the variable itself. Then it doesn't matter whether it's initialized. An example of this is the way you pass `&decimal` to `scanf()`.

Comment: It seems like I have misunderstood where I should declare my variables. As of now, my understanding has been to declare most of the variables inside the main function.                       How do I know, when to declare a variable inside the main function and pass it to another function? And, how do I know when to declare a variable inside another function locally?

Comment: You declare variables where they're needed. If the variable is only needed in the function, you declare it in the function. Parameters are used for communication between functions.

Comment: @Barmar I see. It makes very much sense to me now.

Comment: Sounds like a light bulb came on. You don't want to declare most variables in main(), you want to define them using the smallest scope possible. If they can be local (automatic) make them local. If you understand why it's pointless to define and pass an argument to a function for only that function to use, you've learned something useful.

Answer (score 3):

> If I understood correctly, it is considered as bad practice to pass uninitialized variable into another function because you can easily by mistake use the uninitialized variable inside the function without first initializing it and thus causing undefined behaviour?

In your case, undefined behavior is already invoked by passing the value of the uninitialized variable to the function (see [§6.3.2.1 ¶2 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2)), irrespective of whether the function actually uses the value or not.

But even if it didn't invoke undefined behavior, it would not make sense to pass the value of an uninitialized variable to a function. If you do not care about the initial value and just want to declare a variable to which you can assign a value, you should declare the variable as a local variable instead of as a function parameter.